# I have nginx running but it doesn't serve my react build

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx, npm, vps

I am running on ubuntu. I have nginx running on my computer. I get the welcome page for nginx when I go to the my ip address in the browser but I can't see my react app. I just get a 404 error that says nginx on it. My app is a react app built with create-react app. I made the build with npm run build. I created a site in site-available with nano. which looks like

```
   server {
   server_name 192.168.43.177;
   root home/a/Documents/d/dapp1/mainDapp/client/build/;
   index index.html;
   location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
   }
}
```

at first I ran

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sdft /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sdft
```

That brings up 404 error page in the browser that says nginx on it. I then ran this command

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sdft.nginx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sdft.nginx
```

that bring up "This site can’t be reached" when I go to the ip address in my browser

and every time I edit a file I restart the server but there is no mention of nginx on the error page.

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Running on the belief that you have already loaded the index.html directly with your browser ...

I believe nginx looks for .conf files.
Please try renaming your /etc/nginx/sites-available/sdft.nginx to sdft.conf
Then please try setting your symlink to

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sdft.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sdft.conf
```

If your issue remains unresolved then please try

```
server {
   server_name 192.168.43.177;
   root home/a/Documents/d/dapp1/mainDapp/client/build/;
   index index.html;
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

Noting the change in from index.html to $uri/ location.
Please also validate your system is listening for port 80 and no other services are competing.

Due to reputation limits I can not ask you questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding an another answer.
You want to navigate to the IP (192.168.43.177). Webservers listen to port 80 (by default).

I get the welcome page for nginx when I go to the my ip address.... is it like this?

[image]

If yes nginx is working properly. Goto /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and see what is the path of the root.
[image]

In the example above, path is /var/www/html. You should copy your build to this path, i.e. your index.html must be here.

You dont have to change anything in the default.

Comment: Great Answer....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if all configuration for nginx is passing with:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Is it okay?

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/**sdft** /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**sdft**
```

These filename must match.

and also try adding `listen 80;`, so that it knows what port to listen to.

```
server {
  listen 80; # add this
  server_name 192.168.43.177;
  root home/a/Documents/d/dapp1/mainDapp/client/build/;
  index index.html;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```